# Triple Integration: from Cartesian to Polar Coordinates

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, polar-coordinates

I have to evaluate $\iiint_Q (x+y)^2 dV $, where $Q$ is a solid hemisphere within the bounds $z \ge 0$, $\space x^2+y^2+z^2 \le 4$.

I am assuming that in order to solve the above integral I have to convert the integral and its bounds from cartesian $(x, y, z)$ to spherical coordinates $(r, \theta, \phi)$.

For the $dr$ bound: the distance from origin $ (0, 2) $

For the $d \theta $ bound: the $\theta$ angle range $(0, 2\pi)$

For the $d \phi $ bound: the $\phi$ angle made $(-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2})$

However the answer states that the bounds for $d \phi$ are $(0, \frac{\pi}{2})$

How can this be when the question specifically states "solid hemisphere", which is half of a sphere, not a quarter of a sphere,  which makes it so by by having the bounds $(0, \frac{\pi}{2})$ (at least this is my reasoning).

I am also having trouble converting the actual function $(x+y)^2$ to spherical coordinates, by using the relations

$x=rcos\theta$

$y=rsin\theta$

$r^2=x^2+y^2$

I converted the function $(x+y)^2$ to $ (r^2+2r^2cos\theta sin\theta)$, however this is also incorrect based on the answer provided.

What is the correct way for finding the $d\phi$ bounds and correct function transformation in this situation?

Comment: You only need to go from $0$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$ because you are rotating $\theta$ from $0$ to $2\pi$. Also, you seem to be using formulae for cylindrical coordinates. $\phi$ doesn't even appear in your equations.

Comment: Careful with how you labeled your coordinates. You mention your spherical coordinates $(r,\theta,\phi)$ and you mention the relations $x = r\cos(\theta)$ and etc. At least in the context of spherical coordinates, I use the notation $(\rho,\theta,\phi)$ to avoid confusion with the relations you stated ($x = r\cos(\theta)$). The conversion from rectangular coordinates to spherical coordinates does make use of polar coordinates, but what you get is $x = \rho\sin(\phi)\cos(\theta), y = \rho\sin(\phi)\sin(\theta), z = \rho\cos(\phi)$

Comment: Thank you, does this also apply when making conversions from cartesian to cylindrical coordinates? Or can I still convert a "cartesian" function within an integral to a cylindrical one by just using the relations $x=rcos\theta$ and $y=rsin\theta$  (using your notation) ? @MathNewbie

Comment: @JohnDouma I had another example where I had to evaluate $ \iiint_B (x^2+y^2+z^2)dV$ where B is the unit ball $ x^2+y^2+z^2 \le 1$. Here the bounds for $\theta$ were from $0$ to $2\pi$, but my $\phi$ was from $0$ to $\pi$, because of this I don't think having $\theta$ from $0$ to $2\pi$ is a sufficient condition for $\phi$ to go from $0$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: Think about it in terms of what you are building. You start out by building a spike from $0$ to the boundary of the ball. You picture the little dVs like bricks. You then build a thin orange slice by summing from $0$ to $\pi$. You picture the little spikes being stacked together. Finally, you picture the little slices sweeping out the volume by going from $0$ to $2\pi$. I hope that makes sense. The technique works for all coordinate systems.

Comment: Makes sense now, thank you! @JohnDouma

Comment: @mnmakrets the conversion from cartesian to cyclindrical coordinates is much simpler than the spherical coordinates. $x = r\cos(\theta), y = r\sin(\theta)$, and $z = z$.